# Battery configuration for 5V

Tags: power-supply

I am building board with Atmega328p, in total energy usage is 40mA, now I need to focus on power suplay, on the board is standard V regulator to 5V, what is better baterry configuration, 4 AA which gives me 6V, or 6 AA which gives 9V ? I need optimize space so 4AA would be better, but 6A gives more energy, will the board with 6AA live 33% longer ?

Comment: I think the linear regulator needs at least 5.5~6V to work, so 4AA in series will barely work..

Comment: What type of regulator are you using? If it is a switching regulator you will get longer battery life from the 6AAs, but if it is a linear regulator you will just be wasting more energy as heat.

Edit: If you are using an Arduino Uno then it has a linear regulator.

Comment: Also did you consider running your mcu at 3.3V or less?

Comment: @WesleyLee I need maximum possibile speed, so 3.3 is not an option, I am doing measure every 10 microsecond with option to decrese it to every 5us

Comment: @HarryBeadle I am building my own custom board, so why they used linear ?

Comment: @kosnkov Just because it's cheaper than a switching one. Do you have to use AA batteries?

Comment: There are many microcontrollers capable of running several times faster at 3.3v (or less) than an ATmega can at 5v.

Comment: @HarryBeadle no, but what other options (other cheap battery) do you recommend me to have stable 5V for long time when I don't have access to externall power supply ?

Comment: @kosnkov -- keep in mind that 4 alkaline AAs puts out 3.6V at cutoff -- you'll need a four-switch buck-boost or a SEPIC in order to maintain a stable 5V from 4 AAs.  As Chris Stratton mentioned, is switching to a newer/faster uC not an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no I allready build the prototype with Arduino (my first project after work) next time I will consider different uC, now working on gerbers and focused what is the best option to have stable 5V for my board.

Comment: @kosnkov -- a SEPIC is the simplest solution for your pickle...how much current is your design pulling from the 5V supply?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I put this in my question, 40miliA

Comment: @kosnkov -- sorry I missed that, good to know :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ok so having switching regulator (input 2,7÷11,8V) what battery configuration would you recommend , 4AA, 6AA or other ? and this can be answer instead next comment  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minute you have to use a linear or switching regulator you are going to waste power because you have to supply "juice" to the regulator but, there are quite a few buck-boost designs that I think will work: -

[image]

As you can see this one takes an input voltage as low as 2.7V so it's useful for a single Li-on battery too. The data sheet says that in "selectable burst mode control" (more ripple voltage basically) it's quiescent current can be as low as 50 uA. This is what the efficiency of the circuit looks like for various input voltages: -

[image]

It looks like it's going to be about 80% efficient across the input voltage range with ~40mA output current (whether burst or PWM is used).

How does this compare with an LDO regulator running with a 6V input? 1V will be dropped by the regulator and, at 40mA consumption, the power loss is 40 mW and the total power is 240 mW. This is an efficiency of 83.3 % so it's not much different to the switcher. However, the LDO regulator's efficiency will rise to about 95% as the voltage drops to about 5.1 volts but this of course is shortlived because, below possibly 5V on the input, the output voltage will be significantly lower than 5V and maybe the target circuit will misoperate.

I'd look for a buck-boost regulator that is less high power and I'm sure *this* would prove to be a great solution: -

[image]
[image]

Generally, it has about 90% efficiency for input voltages from 3.6V to 5V so it looks more promising and, you can see that the power loss on very light loads is below about 50 uW.

Given the benefits of being able to use the full range of the battery I'd go for this 2nd solution. It might also be worth considering the [LTC3534](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3534) - it has a 25uA quiescent current draw (light loads) and is more suited to 4 AA cells specifically: -

[image]

Don't forget to try TI too - they also have a pretty good range of switchers and are usually half the price of LT devices. I use LT because I like their search engines and they are reliable devices.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a four-switch topology instead of a SEPIC?  (I'd think the SEPIC would be simpler/easier to source parts for)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel feel free to show some in your answer - I'd be keen to learn what TI (or anyone else) have to offer in this respect - I'm pretty much an LT guy when it comes to regulators - got many thousands of running hours in really difficult situations and environments and I'm more than willing to take a look at one you have in mind. Don't get me wrong though - I use sepic converters in some situations but I also know that having a more complex inductor can put some folk off so go for it. Just because the op has accepted my answer doesn't mean you shouldn't offer up something now.

Comment: Added the LM3478 sample circuit to my answer, just in case anyone was wondering what a SEPIC looks like -- and the magnetics for a SEPIC don't *have* to be complicated; you can do it with a pair of (identical) COTS inductors if you wish.  (I'm also a bit of a LTC partisan myself -- should get LTspiceIV back running over here...)

Comment: finally I will use this regulator since is easy to get in my region http://datasheet.octopart.com/POLOLU-2121-Pololu-datasheet-34175866.pdf

Comment: @kosnkov can you live with 2mA quiescent current OK? Also efficiency is a tad low at ~75% but it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your battery pack (4 presumably alkaline AAs, but the converters I suggest will accommodate NiMH AAs as well) and Vcc requirements (5V at 40mA) -- you will want a [SEPIC converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter) topology; fortunately, many boost controller and converter ICs can also implement a SEPIC.  Examples include the [LM3478](http://www.ti.com/product/lm3478) and the [LT1949](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1949) if you don't mind prototying with SO-8 parts -- the LM3478 is a controller that uses an external MOSFET switch (you can use most logic level N-ch FETs in your application as the switch currents are so low), while the LT1949 has a built-in power BJT switch.  If you require a through-hole package for prototyping purposes, you can use the [LT1307](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1307) in an 8-pin DIP package instead, which also has a built-in power switch.

With all three of those parts, though -- your best bet is to use a simple (hand-etched or milled is fine) PCB for prototyping due to the need to keep lead and trace lengths short and loop areas *small*.  If that's not an option, the LT1307 *should* give satisfactory performance when built on a perfboard provided sufficient care is taken with component placement.

Also, I'd recommend getting a couple of chunky ferrite-core inductors (of the same value) for your prototyping -- you can always buy smaller inductors for the final PCB layout!  For instance, a pair of [Bourns RLB0712s of the appropriate value](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/RLB0712-100KL/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsg%252by3WlYCkUz6k%252bUjgS74eALmS2CTE%252bUU%3d) should do the trick for the LT1307...you can always pick up more values if you wish, too!  (The Bourns RLB series is available in standard E12 values, and the 0712 and smaller versions are breadboard compatible...)

An example SEPIC configuration (taken straight from the datasheet) for the LM3478 is shown below -- the LTC chips I linked are broadly similar, but have the switching transistor and current sensing built-in.

[image: LM3478 SEPIC schematic, from the datasheet]

Comment: Quiescent current is a couple of mA which won't matter to the OP and efficiency is only about 80% - this is why I tend to go for the non sepic solution - basically a H bridge is totally synchronous and there's no diode drop to steal 0.7 volts at 50 mA. Power loss in this is approx 35mW whereas the LTC3129 burns only 50 uW (low-load) and is closer to 90% efficient on 40mA loads and therefore only wasting maybe 22 mW. It all adds up!